# How to debug async/await (multi-threading) issue with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, entity-framework, asynchronous

I have "inherited" a multi-tier ASP.NET Core project that uses AutoMapper and EntityFramework.
It also makes heavy use of async/await.

As soon as there are multiple simultaneous requests, I receive an InvalidOperationException from EntityFramework, informing me that "A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed."

I have already played around with the lifetime settings (everything was set to Scoped) and thought setting everything to Transient had solved the issue as a temporary workaround. But after slightly cleaning up my code, so that I could merge it into the main branch, the problem returned.

Anyway, I figured it would be better to create a sample project to replicate the problem. But that didn't work either. I tried to copy the exact project structure, use the same (outdated) versions of Entity Framework etc., but no luck. Everything works fine, both with "Scoped" and "Transient" lifetime.

How would you try to debug this problem?
I have already added code to log the addresses in memory, like so:

```cs
    private static string GetAddress(object a)
    {
        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(a, GCHandleType.Weak);
        IntPtr pointer = GCHandle.ToIntPtr(handle);
        handle.Free();
        return "0x" + pointer.ToString("X");
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("######## {0:00}: Controller {1}\tManager {2}\tRepository\t\t\tContext\t\t\t(DepartmentController.GetAll)", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, GetAddress(this), GetAddress(_departmentManager));
        Thread.Sleep(2000); // To make it easier to reproduce the issue
        var departments = await _departmentManager.GetAllItems();
        return new ObjectResult(GetJsonObject(departments));
    }
```

But this didn't really help much. With the lifetime set to "Transient", all instances have different addresses on different threads, so it doesn't really look like the threads are accessing each other's DbContexts.
I suspect there's a very subtle problem somewhere, like a missing keyword or so, that is running code on a different thread.
I just can't seem to figure out what it is...
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide some relevant portions of code?

Comment: Share that sample project that reproduces the error

Comment: You might turn on EF logging on the context or SQL Trace and then use the last log entry and the exception stack trace to track down the two bits of code that are accessing the DbContext at the same time.  Also look for an async call without an await.  In that case the code will continue and may run another query before the first one completes.

Comment: If everything works fine in a new project, do a comparison of your project-level files. Particularly `web.config`.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue in the sample project. Comparing on the file level does not really help because the original project is quite large. In my sample project I have tried to replicate the structure with all relevant code - but to no avail. I used LocalDB in the sample project, but I guess that should not matter... I will try with EF logging. Looking for an async call without await is a good idea, thank you! Pretty much all DB calls are affected, so I guess the architecture itself is flawed, it's not just one method that has this issue.